# Slim Application Error: Setting Controller slim 3

Tags: php, slim

I am trying to set up my HomeController, I am on a macbook. I am not sure why I keep getting the error class not found:

```
Slim Application Error
The application could not run because of the following error:

Details
Type: Error
Message: Class 'App\Controllers\HomeController' not found
File: /Users/username/Documents/webapps/site/src/dependencies.php
Line: 39
Trace
```

Here is my controller:

```
<?php

namespace \App\Controllers;

class HomeController {
    protected $container;

    // constructor receives container instance
    public function __construct(ContainerInterface $container) {
        $this->container = $container;
    }

    public function index($request, $response){
        return 'home Controller';
    }

    public function videos($request, $response){
        return 'Video Controller';
    }
}
```

And Composer.json

```
"autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "src/"
        }
    },
```

And routes:

```
$app->get('/videos', \HomeController::class . ':videos');
```

And dependencies.php

```
 $container['HomeController'] = function ($container) {
        return new \App\Controllers\HomeController;
    };
```

I would thought everything should work out well..
What am am I missing?

Comment: Your route is also using wrong class name. There is no `\HomeController` class, it should be `\App\Controllers\HomeController`. And where did you save `HomeController.php`?

Answer (score 0):

make sure that you call properly your class name in router - resolver will try to load instance from Container and by your example it is wrong
it should be

```
$app->get('/videos', 'HomeController:videos'); // because class \HomeController::class does not exists an it is named just 'HomeController' in your container
```

also on MacOS be aware that your namespace must follow folder structure and folder structure IS case-sensitive , so if your `Controllers` folder is not with capital C, you might have issues with class loader